# Reason to make viewed count bold

Tags: support, bug, design, localization

Recent site build leads to loosing translation in localized sites for string with the post view count. Bug report for ruSO: [Перевод счётчика количества просмотров](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5418/176217).

I've made new translation in Transifex. But what's curiour for me: why old string `$viewsPretty$ times` was replaced with `**$viewsPretty$ times**`? I.e. adding bold markdown here doesn't work due to current style for that block. E.g.

> [image: 32 times]

You can see that in html-source here is `<b>` tags around `32 times`, which became from double stars `**` from the new string:

```
<p class="label-key">
    <b>32 times</b>
</p>
```

Comment: I just checked, the Japanese site still has it in Japanese (either somebody fixed it or it wasn't affected), but the Portuguese site has it in English now, too. I didn't check any other sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does have an effect. That entire pane is styled as a table where both the left column ("asked", "views", etc.) and the right column (the values) are styled the same: As a `p class="label-key"` inside a `td`:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <p class="label-key">asked</p>
    </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 10px">
        <p class="label-key" title="2017-06-07 06:50:39Z"><b>yesterday</b></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The `b` styling makes the text darker. With it, the values are black. Without it, they're gray like the left column. For example, here is how it normally appears:

[image]

And here is how it appears if you remove all the bold tags from the values on the right:

[image]

The relevant styling is in [*all.css*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/all.css?v=92d4831501e2):

```css
.label-key {
    color: #9199a1;
    font-size: 14px
}

.label-key b, .label-key strong {
    color: #3b4045;
    font-weight: normal
}
```

So, it may be a philosophically odd way to accomplish that goal, but, yes, it has an important effect, and you do need to include the `**` bold markdown in your value strings.

---

As for why it was changed and the localized string loss, not sure, unfortunately. Maybe they did a massive "find/replace" style thing by accident and instead of surrounding the existing localized strings with `**`, they replaced them all with English.

It doesn't appear that the Russian site was the only one affected. I just checked, the Japanese site still has it in Japanese (either somebody fixed it or it wasn't affected), but the Portuguese site has it in English now, too. I didn't check any other sites.

Comment: How did it work before? I'm pretty sure that old string hasn't `**`. Otherwise, the translation would not be reset on ruSO.

Comment: @alexolut Not sure. But I understand your bug report now. Maybe they did a massive "find/replace" style thing by accident and instead of surrounding the existing localized strings with `**`, they replaced them all with English.

Comment: @JasonC I work with the SO CSS everyday and _I'm_ amazed at some of the decisions made (myself included). Regularly I have moments that make me think, 'What is going on here?' 

Comment: Seems actual change was `**$__count$ times**` → `**$viewsPretty$ times**`. Not `$viewsPretty$ times` → `**$viewsPretty$ times**`. I.e. bold remains where it was.

Comment: I found source of change on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251510